# Zsh snippets implementation

Tags: zsh

Is there any way to implement expandable snippets in zsh?

I'd like to be able to write `ssh ssh_alias -t :tmux` press tab and this would be expanded to the `ssh ssh_alias -t "tmux a||tmux"

I want this behavior to be global, so this snippet would work in other places for instance `mosh ssh_alias - :tmux`

Finally, I want this behavior to be over command-specific completion rules.

At this moment, I'm achieving something similar with 'Dash'

Comment: Needs an OS tag...

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin: [zsh-snippets](https://github.com/willghatch/zsh-snippets). Use it with a plugin manager like [zplugin](https://github.com/psprint/zplugin). It binds to Meta-x, tested it – works. Here is complete zplugin report on it:

```
Plugin report for willghatch/zsh-snippets
-----------------------------------------
Source snippets.plugin.zsh
Zle -N snippet-expand
Bindkey ^[x snippet-expand
Zle -N run-help-list-snippets

Functions created:
help-list-snippets run-help-list-snippets
snippet-add        snippet-expand

Variables added or redefined:
snippets  [ "" -> association ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using *Global Aliases*. In contrast to regular aliases, they are expanded no matter where they appear in a command line not only in the command position.

```
alias -g :tmux='"tmux a || tmux"'
```

With that, `:tmux` will be expanded to (replaced by) `"tmux a || tmux"`. Note that you need to quote it twice, once for the definition and once for the final command line. So, if you run

```
ssh ssh_alias -t :tmux
```

`zsh` will replace `:tmux` and execute

```
ssh ssh_alias -t "tmux a || tmux"
```

Usually the expansion is not shown when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> - just like with regular aliases. That being said, the `_expand_alias` widget can be used to expand aliases. You can either call it directly (in emacs mode it is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>a</kbd>. There is no default binding in vi mode, but you can run it from vicmd mode with `:_expand_alias`) or add it to the `completer` zstyle.

Comment: Well, I'm using vi mode, and yes it is not shown when pressing `Tab`.

Comment: In vi mode you can run any widget by name after pressing `:`.